# How can I pause the image processing in Topaz Gigapixel AI?

Tags: post-processing

I use Topaz Gigapixel AI for image postprocessing. It can take a while to process a fair amount of images. How can I pause the image processing in Topaz Gigapixel AI?

[image]

If I click on "Cancel processing", I don't see any option to resume.

Answer (score 2):

While it’s still running uncheck the images that it hasn’t ran yet. After it finishes the one it’s on it’ll stop hence it’s the last job to run. Then you can reverse your selection and start it again when you want to finish.